# Transform $3D$ grid to dimetric projection

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations, projective-geometry, isometry

I'm rendering rhombus textures in a $3D$ world:
[image: Rhombus textures]

Here are the rhombus textures rendered in a grid in perspective projection with $FOV = 45^\circ$:
[image: Rhombus textures rendered as a grid in perspective projection]

Here is the same grid scene, but in dimetric orthographic projection, with yaw $= 30^\circ$ and pitch $= 45^\circ$:
[image: Square textures rendered as a grid in dimetric orthographic projection]

I would like to remove this spacing between the rhombuses in orthographic projection:

[image: Spacing between rhombuses in dimetric projection]

And render it like this:

[image: Rhombuses in dimetric projection without spacing]

I have tried multiplying both the $X$ and $Z$ coordinates of the grid by $0.695$, which produced this result:

[image: Rhombuses in dimetric projection with grid multiplied by 0.695]

It's closer but not correct. How can I transform the $3D$ grid coordinates so that the rhombuses appear contiguous when rendered in dimetric projection?

Comment: Not enough information. Can you get the original XYZ coordinates of every corner in the black, blue, and green squares, the most on the left side of the image?

Comment: @Andrei I'm not sure what you mean. I'm drawing 2D pictures of rhombuses on a 3D grid. I want to know how to arrange the grid in such a way that when it is viewed through orthographic dimetric projection, the rhombuses line up contiguously.

Comment: _"I'm rendering rhombus textures in a 3D world"_ -- Sorry, for me your setup is not clear. Are the rhombs defined flat side by side? If not, what is the result if you do so? If it comes out wrong too, what happens if you define squares or rectangles edge aligned? If it does not work as you expect, there are three possible errors (or combinations thereof), your setup, the used software, or your expectation. So start with something simple and go on only if that worked.

Comment: @m-stgt Thanks for the hint, it's actually a problem with cylindrical billboarding that I'm using to make the rhombs face the camera. The rhombs must be equal in height, but due to the tilt of camera the height is distorted as up-rotation is locked in cylindrical billboarding.

Answer (score 1):

The correct multiplier for dimetric projection is `sqrt(2)` which is around `1.4142`.

The `0.695` multiplier was close (`1 / 0.695` = `1.4388`) but it doesn't work for a different reason.

The rhombs are facing the camera using cylindrical billboarding, in which the object is facing the camera but cannot rotate upwards:

[image: Cylindrical billboarding showcase]

This means that at a narrow angle, objects height will be distorted:

[image: Cylindrical billboarding perspective]

Compared to spherical billboarding (object always rotates to face camera plane):

[image: Spherical billboarding perspective]

Due to this distortion, the multiplier did not work even though the projection was orthographic. Here's orthographic projection with `sqrt(2)` multiplier with cylindrical billboarding:

[image: Spherical billboarding orthographic]

The same `sqrt(2)` multiplier with spherical billboarding produces the desired result:

[image: Cylindrical billboarding orthographic]